# Can Mathematica factor a polynomial over an algebraic number field?

Tags: polynomials, factorization

If I input:

```
Factor[x^2 + x + 1, Extension -> Sqrt[-3]]
```

Mathematica returns:

```
1/4 (-I + Sqrt[3] - 2 I x) (I + Sqrt[3] + 2 I x)
```

The coefficients in the factorization are not in $Q(\sqrt{-3})$.  I was expecting something like:

$$  (x - z_3)*(x - (z_3)^2) $$

where $z_3$ is a primitive third root of unity.

Comment: A similar output is produced by `Factor[x^2 + 2, Extension -> Sqrt[-2]]`.  Interestingly, the output of `Factor[x^2 + 1, Extension -> Sqrt[-1]]` is of the form you were originally expecting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mathematica uses FactorTerms to remove content from factors. Since Sqrt[-3] evaluates to I Sqrt[3], I gets factored out as "content".

```
FactorTerms[1 + I Sqrt[3] + 2 x]

I (-I + Sqrt[3] - (2 I) x)
```

You can use AlgebraicNumber to make extension generators atomic.

```
Factor[x^2 + x + 1, Extension -> AlgebraicNumber[I Sqrt[3], {0, 1}]]

((2 x + AlgebraicNumber[I Sqrt[3], {1, -1}])
(2 x + AlgebraicNumber[I Sqrt[3], {1, 1}])) / 4

ToRadicals[%]//InputForm

((1 - I*Sqrt[3] + 2*x)*(1 + I*Sqrt[3] + 2*x))/4
```